# Adding Counter objects with addition empty

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand this behavior:

```
>>> Counter({'a':0})
Counter({'a': 0})
>>> Counter({'a':0}) + Counter({'a':0})
Counter()
>>> len(Counter({'a':0}))
1
>>> len(Counter({'a':0}) + Counter({'a':0}))
0
```

This seems inconsistent to me -- thoughts?

Comment: The documentation is quite explicit about this; keys with count 0 are dropped when summing two Counters.

Comment: I looked for documentation on this behavior and couldn't find it, here's where I was looking. Any other suggestions where to look? https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Comment: A quote from that page: *"Addition and subtraction combine counters by adding or subtracting the counts of corresponding elements. Intersection and union return the minimum and maximum of corresponding counts. Each operation can accept inputs with signed counts, but the output will **exclude results with counts of zero or less**."*

Comment: It is documented on that page; my answer to the linked duplicate highlights the exact phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not inconsistent. While summing two `Counter` classes, negative and zero counts are ignored. Go through the Notes section in this for more details: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter